# What is best practice for flask error handling?

Tags: python, exception, flask

For returning a `400/500` response to clients in a `flask` webapp, I've seen the following conventions:

### Abort

```
import flask
def index(arg):
    return flask.abort("Invalid request", 400)
```

### Tuple

```
def index(arg):
    return ("Invalid request", 400)
```

### Response

```
import flask
def index(arg):
    return flask.Response("Invalid request", 400)
```

What are the difference and when would one be preferred?

#### Related question

Coming from `Java/Spring`, I am used to defining a custom exception with a status code associated with it and then anytime the application throws that exception, a response with that status code is automatically returned to the user (instead of having to explicitly catch it and return a response as shown above).  Is this possible in `flask`?  This is my little wrapped attempt

```
from flask import Response

class FooException(Exception):
    """ Binds optional status code and encapsulates returing Response when error is caught """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        code = kwargs.pop('code', 400)
        Exception.__init__(self)
        self.code = code

    def as_http_error(self):
        return Response(str(self), self.code)
```

Then to use

```
try:
    something()
catch FooException as ex:
    return ex.as_http_error()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best practice is to create your custom exception classes and then registering with Flask app through error handler decorator. You can raise a custom exception from business logic and then allow the Flask Error Handler to handle any of custom defined exceptions. (Similar way it's done in Spring as well.)

You can use the decorator like below and register your custom exception.

```py
@app.errorhandler(FooException)
def handle_foo_exception(error):
    response = jsonify(error.to_dict())
    response.status_code = error.status_code
    return response
```

You can read more about it here [Implementing API Exceptions](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/apierrors/)